# How to set FontSize of a Textblock, which is in a Viewbox

Tags: wpf, vb.net, wpf-controls, textblock, font-size

I can't set the `FontSize` of the `Text` in a `TextBlock`, since the `TextBox` is in a `Viewbox`. Why?

```
<Grid Margin="35,30,35,0" ShowGridLines="False" >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="270 px" Width="2*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition  />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" />
    <Viewbox>
        <TextBlock  Margin="10,5,0,5" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">Team:</TextBlock>
    </Viewbox>
    <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" />
    <TextBlock Margin="10,5,0,5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">Beschreibung:</TextBlock>
    <Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" />
    <TextBlock Margin="10,5,0,5" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">Milestone:</TextBlock>
    <Border Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" />
    <TextBlock Margin="10,5,0,5" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0">Status:</TextBlock>
    <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,1,1,0" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="tb_Team_dyn" Margin="10,5,0,5"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
               FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Data.Team}" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
    <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,1,1,0" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="tb_Descr_dyn" Margin="10,5,0,5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
               FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Data.Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    <Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,1,1,0" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="tb_Milestone_dyn" Margin="10,5,0,5" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"
               FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Data.Milestone}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    <Border Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,1,1,1" />
    <StackPanel Margin="10,5,0,5" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image  x:Name="imgSmile" MaxWidth="38" Source="{Binding Data.Smiley}" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="tb_Status_dyn" Margin="{Binding Data.SmileyMargin}"
                   Foreground="{Binding Data.Col}" FontWeight="Bold"
                   Text="{Binding Data.Status}" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I can set the `FontSize`s of all of the `TextBlock`s but not of the `TextBlock` which is in the `Viewbox`.

Comment: The purpose of a viewbox is to stretch its content... so if you don't want the size of the text in the textblock to stretch, why the viewbox?

Comment: i want to stretch the size of the textblock.. but I cant set a "start"font-size. My window starts maximized and so the font is very big.. but the fontsize should be smaller.. but i cant set it..

Comment: I'm still not clear what you're trying to accomplish - you want the textblock to stretch without stretching the text? This is not possible. If you want a static sized string (with a static font) placed withing a region that stretches, try a viewbox containing a uniform grid, with 1x1 cells, with the textblock inside of that. There are probably dozens of other layout possibilities that will work. Typically I use  combination of DockPanels with LastChildFill=True for something like this.

Comment: I think the Viewbox is very helpful for me. I want the stretch the text. The stretching works. But now my problem is: Setting the font-size of the TextBlock with FontSize="16" is uneffectly. My window starts maximized. So the font is about 48px. But the font should be, when the window is maximized 16px and not 48px. And I don't know, how to set, because like already said, FontSize="16" is uneffectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that the FontSize sets the actual size of the text but the Viewbox then scales it after the text is laid out and rendered. You will see the same effect if you place an element with a fixed Width and Height in a Viewbox. The Viewbox doesn't change the Width, Height, or FontSize properties themselves but the final rendering appears different.

What you're actually looking for is an initial layout for the Viewbox itself that will make its initial size equal to that of the TextBlock, which will effectively set the scaling of the Viewbox to 1:1. You can achieve this in a number of ways depending on your application (directly in code, Bindings with ValueConverters, etc) but the basic method would be to measure the initial size of a parent element and set appropriate Margins to scale down the Viewbox within the layout area assigned to it. This would then allow the Viewbox to change size along with its parent as it maintains the Margins that you set. Also look at the StretchDirection, MinHeight, and MinWidth on the Viewbox.

Answer (score 1):

Some sample code would be helpful. Off the top of my head... is the textbox set to multiline? If not the inner text will probably stretch along with the textbox.